# How to add arguments to karma-mocha?

Tags: unit-testing, typescript, karma-mocha

I have set unit testing for a TypeScript project. From command line this works fine:

```
mocha --compilers ts:typescript-require ./source/**/*.spec.ts
```

Now, I have added mocha and chai to my karma file like so:

```
...
frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai'],
...
```

How do I include the argument `compilers ts:typescript-require` to mocha using the `karma.conf.js` file using this section:

```
...
client: {
  mocha: {
    // I assume it goes here?
  }
},
...
```

An example would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So... I have some good news and some bad news. First the bad news.

`typescript-require` works as a Mocha plug-in because at the command-line, Mocha and Typescript are both running in the context of Node.js. However, when you use Karma, Mocha actually runs in the context of the browser instead. Browsers don't have built-in module loaders (implementations of `require(...)`), and there are commonly two strategies to remedy that:

1. Use a dev-time transformer (e.g. Browserify or Webpack) that analyses your `require(...)` calls and replaces it with their loading code.
2. Add an in-browser loader that supports require (e.g. SystemJS or RequireJS).

There are different styles of loaders/require(...) behaviour. However, since your code works in the command-line (Node.js), I'm guessing you want a loader that can emulate Node.js, which is family #1.

Ok, now the *good news*. It seems like you wanted to run your tests without having to do a separate step to convert your Typescript to JS, since the plugin you were using does that "on the fly". You ***can*** do similar things in Karma, you just need to run it in the Karma layer instead of the Mocha layer. A Karma plugin that does that is https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-typescript-preprocessor.

Good luck!